# MySQL subquery over DISTINCT query results

Tags: mysql, subquery

I have a Products table, with a unique column named 'code'.
The code starts with a letter, and then has subsequent numbers. So, product codes are like this:
A01, A02, A03, A04, B01, B02, C01, C02, C03, and so on...

How can I get the highest number for each letter? (i.e. the current counter for A which would be 04, for B which is 02, for C which is 03, etc)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your data have constant value?
If yes, you can use
MAX with GROUP BY LEFT(col,1)

example :
SELECT MAX(RIGHT(col,2) FROM table GROUP BY LEFT(col,1)